# while making whole div clickable a tag is self close since where it start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make my whole div clickable but when i put my div tag code in anchor tag then its not clickable at all, even when i check console there a tag is closing just after it starting please help. thanks in advance.

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="post-media">
                <a href="#"><img src="upload/testi_01.png" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- end media -->
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p> <strong>Name (fi / intermediary ? - entrepreneur to assist for bank finanae)</strong> </p>
            <p> <i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Industry </p>
            <p> <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Type Of Finance </p>
            <p> <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Amount </p>
            <p> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; location </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="job-meta">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <p>13th Feb, 2018</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end meta -->
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <div class="job-meta text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Connect  Now &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
</a>
```

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: @Hash OPs syntax is totally wrong, can't have nested `a` tags.

Comment: ya that is right. read it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid - you have nested `a` tags - you cannot have `a` within an `a`.

It would be better to add a click handler to the div, and then get that to trigger the 'a' within.

Answer (score 0):

Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

[image]

In [w3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html) it is mentioned: **12.2.2 Nested links are illegal**